# Notepad ++ Search and replace the text 2 specific lines only

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, line

I have to replace 2 lines in every project.wsCFG file if line 17 contains a specific Pattern.
Files with this name existing in a lot of subdirectories of a project folder.

Example:
if line 17 contains the pattern "ArticleConnectionStringSQL" val="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1"

replace: line 14 with: `<P id="ArticleConnectionType" val="SQL" />`
and replace line 17 with: `<P id="ArticleConnectionStringSQL" val="Data Source=sv-it-db-6;Initial Catalog=20200526_WSCAD_IPP;Integrated Security=True" />`

I can search within notepadd++ for these files, that's no problem. And I think the best way to replace these two lines is with regular expression.

Can anybody help me with the regular expression code for this?

Thanks.

Andreas

Comment: Was the answer helpful in solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the first 13 lines in group 1 using a repeating non capturing group and a quantifier.

Then match line 14 and capture in the second capturing group matching line 15 and 16 using the same mechanism as for the first group.

Then match your pattern in line 17.

```
\A((?:.*\R){13}).*((?:\R.*){2})\R.*ArticleConnectionStringSQL" val="Provider=SQLOLEDB\.1.*
```

*In parts*

- `\A` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:.*\R){13}` Match first 13 lines where `\R` matches a unicode newline sequence
- `)` Close group
- `.*` Match line 14
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:\R.*){2}` Match line 15 and 16
- `)` Close group
- `\R.*ArticleConnectionStringSQL" val="Provider=SQLOLEDB\.1.*` Match line 17 with your string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ehDZ0t/1)

In the replacement, use the 2 capturing groups with your replacement values.

```
$1<P id="ArticleConnectionType" val="SQL" />$2\n<P id="ArticleConnectionStringSQL" val="Data Source=sv-it-db-6;Initial Catalog=20200526_WSCAD_IPP;Integrated Security=True" />
```

[image]